# Convert from ether to wei using go-ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there any function in go-ethereum, which can convert values from ether to wei and vice-versa?

I should notice, that I'm **not** using `geth` as standalone app, I'm using `go-ethereum` as imported libraries to my golang app, so using console is not an option

I want to ask if go-etherum has some converter function inside it, or, probably, someone know other non-official library at go, which can convert Ethereum values.

Answer (score 1):

Go-ethereum exposes the web3 API:

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/javascript-console

So, if `amt` is in ETH, you can do:

```
web3.utils.toWei(amt,'ether')
```

and

```
web3.utils.fromWei(amt, 'ether')
```

See:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-utils.html#towei

Comment: Ok, I should add that I'm not using geth as _standalone_ app, I'm using `go-ethereum` modules as imported libraries to my golang app (for interaction with smart-contracts, transaction, event's, etc)

Therefore I cannot use java-script console

So, Im asking -- is there anything **inside** go-ethereum for making such conversions?

Or probably you know any other go-lib for doing so?

Comment: @JackBekket I'm not sure of the arithmetic precision in go, but could you just divide or multiply by `1000000000000000000`?  I don't know re. the go-ethereum internals. Why not update your question with this context?

Comment: Yes, currently the only solution is to do amt*10^18, but it feels unsafety and not really convinient as such simple functions from web3 :c

Also, probably you know, why there are no implementation of web3 in go?

Comment: @JackBekket I don't know, and I also don't know why there'd need to be one either.

Answer (score 0):

Float*10^18 will overflow fairly quickly. I am using the following function:

```
func FloatTo18z(amount float64) *big.Int {
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%f", amount)
    a := strings.Split(s, ".")
    for i := 0; i < 18; i++ {
        if len(a) > 1 && len(a[1]) > i {
            a[0] += string(a[1][i])
        } else {
            a[0] += "0"
        }
    }
    b, ok := new(big.Int).SetString(a[0], 10)
    if !ok {
        panic("Could not set big.Int string for value " + s)
    }
    return b
}
```